# Can we call rest endpoint from aspect implementation class in AOP ? I need to use this AOP lib project in other project also

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I am new in Java, Here I have created one Spring AOP project. I have created two aspect annotation which I need to use in other service project.
Please see the below AspectImplementation class >>>>

```
package com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.jp.genesis.model.Employee;
import com.jp.genesis.model.ReturnParameters;



@Aspect
@Component
public class GenesisApiAuditAspect {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenesisApiAuditAspect.class);
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private ReturnParameters returnParam;
    @Before("@annotation(GenesisApiAudit)")
    public void logApiRequest(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();        
        Class<? extends Object> className = jp.getTarget().getClass();
         
                
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.getKind() : " + jp.getKind()); //method-execution
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.getSignature(): " + jp.getSignature()); //ResponseEntity com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController.getEmployee(int)
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.getSourceLocation(): " + jp.getSourceLocation()); //org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint$SourceLocationImpl@b203da53
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.getTarget(): " + jp.getTarget()); //com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController@e3a1b9f
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.getTarget(): Class name" + jp.getTarget().getClass()); 
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.getThis().toString(): " + jp.getThis().toString()); //com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController@e3a1b9f

        Object[] argList = jp.getArgs();
        if(null != argList) {
            for (Object object : argList) {
                LOG.info("@@@@ ... jp.getArgs(): " + object.toString());
                //returnParam.setMethodArgs(object.toString());
            }
            
        }


        LOG.info("@@@@ Executing method 1 : " + methodName); // getEmployee
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.toLongString() 1 : " + jp.toLongString()); // execution(public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController.getEmployee(int))
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.toShortString() 1 : " + jp.toShortString()); //execution(EmployeeRestController.getEmployee(..))
        LOG.info("@@@@ jp.toString() 1 : " + jp.toString());  // execution(ResponseEntity com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController.getEmployee(int))
        //returnParam.setClassName(className);
        returnParam.setMethodName("bhagesh");
        
        restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/person/update", returnParam,ReturnParameters.class);

        //System.out.println("Id: " + employee.getEmpId());

    }

    @Before("@annotation(GenesisApiAuditLight)")
    public void logApiRequestLight(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();        

        LOG.info("@@@@---- jp.getSignature(): " + jp.getSignature()); //ResponseEntity com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController.getEmployee(int)
        LOG.info("@@@@---- Executing method 1 : " + methodName); // getEmployee
        LOG.info("@@@@---- jp.toString() 1 : " + jp.toString());  // execution(ResponseEntity com.jp.genesis.controller.EmployeeRestController.getEmployee(int))     

        try {
            Object[] argList = jp.getArgs();
            if(null != argList) {
                for (Object object : argList) {
                    LOG.info("@@@@ ... argument : " + object.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex ) {
            LOG.error("@@@@ ... Exception in : " + jp.getSignature());
        }

    }


    @AfterReturning(pointcut="@annotation(GenesisApiAuditLight)", returning="returnObject") 
    public void logApiResponseLight(Object returnObject) {  
        if (null != returnObject) {
            if (returnObject instanceof ResponseEntity ){
//              ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = (ResponseEntity<?>)returnObject;
                ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = (ResponseEntity<?>)returnObject;
                LOG.info("*** responseEntity.getStatusCode() : " + responseEntity.getStatusCode()); // 200 OK
                LOG.info("*** responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() : " + responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue()); // 200

                if (responseEntity.getBody() instanceof Optional<?>) {
                    LOG.info("@@@@ *** responseEntity.getBody() : " + ((Optional<Employee>)responseEntity.getBody()).get().getFirst_name()); //Optional[com.jp.genesis.model.Employee@719afb22]
                    LOG.info("@@@@ *** (Optional<Employee>) responseEntity.getBody() : " + ((Optional<Employee>)responseEntity.getBody()).get().toString()); 
                }
                else if (responseEntity.getBody() instanceof String) {
                    LOG.info("@@@@ *** responseEntity.getBody() : " + (responseEntity.getBody()).toString()); 
                }
                LOG.info("@@@@ *** responseEntity.getBody() : " + (responseEntity.getBody()).toString()); 
            }
            else {
                LOG.info("@@@@ *** not instance of ResponseEntity **** ");
            }
        }
        else {
            LOG.info("@@@@ *** if (null == returnObject)  **** ");
        }
        LOG.info("@@@@ ---- returnObject.toString()  : " + returnObject.toString());    //<200 OK OK,Optional[com.jp.genesis.model.Employee@35b2478],[]>
        LOG.info("@@@@ ---- returnObject.getClass().getCanonicalName(): " + returnObject.getClass().getCanonicalName()); // org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
        returnParam.setReturnObjects(returnObject.toString());
        //restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/jp/genesis/restendpoints2", returnParam,ReturnParameters.class);
    }

    //    @AfterThrowing("restControllerApplicationPackagePointCut() || restControllerPointCut()")
    //    public void logApiError() {
    //          LOG.info("**** API error case  : ");        
    //    }


}
```

In this code, I have used restTemplate for calling a post request/
Later I had given the maven build, Which is successful. Now this project dependency I have added in another service project, When I am giving another project maven Build I am getting Build Failure.

Please see below logs >>>>>>

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field restTemplate in com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect.GenesisApiAuditAspect required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' in your configuration.

2020-09-10 12:18:25.274 ERROR 2664 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5e600dd5] to prepare test instance [com.example.demo.SpringTestAuditApplicationTests@79d743e6]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) [spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'genesisApiAuditAspect': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 84 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.344 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.SpringTestAuditApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.056 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'genesisApiAuditAspect': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   SpringTestAuditApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load App...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here I have doubt, I am getting Build failure because of restTemplate code or any other thing is wrong. Can we use restTemplate or not, If we can use so Is there anything missed in this code or Is there any other alternate I need to try.

Any Help would be appreciate.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ofcourse you can however you are now requiring your other projects to always have a web dependency and configure a `RestTemplate`. This might not always be the case. Also you don't get a build error, you are getting a test error due to the project not defining a `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Hi M.Deinum, I defined RestTemplate in AOP Lib project main class. public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SpringApiAoPLibraryApplication.class, args);
 }
 @Bean
 public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
     return new RestTemplate();
 } You are talking about same, Or I am missing any annotation or configuration. How we can solve this issue ??

Comment: "your other(using) projects" not "AOP lib project";)

Comment: @xerx593, I defined RestTemplate in Other(using) project also, But it's not working. In Build failure description I am able to read. Field returnParam in com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect.GenesisApiAuditAspect required a bean of type 'com.jp.genesis.model.ReturnParameters' that could not be found. I have created RetuenParameters bean class in AOP lib project also. SO because of this I m getting error ??

Comment: That is nice for your lib but not your consumers. Your consumers only know about your aspect not about the class containing a `main` method nor are they going to run that. What you should do is provide an `@Configuration` class that creates (optionally!) the needed beans for your aspect. That class should also be loaded as part of the component scanning.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I have selected skip tests, Now Build is success. But getting error When I am running the application. ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field person in com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect.GenesisApiAuditAspect required a bean of type 'com.jp.genesis.model.Person' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jp.genesis.model.Person' in your configuration.

Comment: Have you actually **read** my comment. Skipping tests won't solve a thing as your main class is still not involved. As stated create an `@Configuration` class that is also being used in your project that uses your aop library.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, It's working fine. Do we have any alternate or any other annotation instead of Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() { return new RestTemplate(); }